# Excel -Using a lower ranked value to display associated cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

i am using excel 2013. From below, e.g. if C2 is ranked 2nd, E2 value takes the value of 1st rank,i.e. 0.008. if C6 is ranked 6th, E6 takes the value of 5th rank, i.e. 0.8.

my question is how to write the formula for E2  to E7? i guess we need array formula? formula is much prefered over vba.

thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula in E2 copied down

`=IFERROR(SMALL(D$2:D$7,C2-1),0)`

If you want you can do without the ranking column, e.g. based on column D alone, you can use this version

`=IFERROR(SMALL(D$2:D$7,RANK(D2,D$2:D$7,1)-1),0)`